# Vue v-model is not binding after deep copy in Mounted hook?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have an input field that is v-modeled to formData.name

this.portfolio is a Vuex mutation which is being set to this.formData on the mounted hook.

It makes sense why formData.name is being undefined because this.portfolio does not have a name property.

So how do I make the v-model work again for input?

```
data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        name: 'John'
      }
},
async mounted() {
  console.log(this.formData.name) // Returns with 'John'
  this.formData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.portfolio))
  console.log(this.formData.name) // Returns undefined
}
```

This is a weird bug that has given me hours of problems with no fix. I have two files both written the same way with the mounted with a deep copy and set to this.formData.

However, on one file, the v-model starts working after mounting and on this file, it does not. I have done nothing specifically to re-set the v-model and yet when I go to submit the form on this file, if I console.log(this.formData.name) it will return false or undefined while the other file will have the proper v-model set.

Any ideas?

Comment: If `this.portfolio` doesn't have a name property you could just keep the one you have. `this.formData = {...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.portfolio)),name:this.formData.name}`

Comment: Thanks this will work. I was mainly curious of the weird divergent behavior and seeing if I missed something about mounted or reactivity I'm not aware of